# Converting a windows Run.bat to a Run.sh

Tags: windows, java, paths

```batch
"c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_75\bin\java.exe" -noverify -Xbootclasspath/a:"LSA.jar";"lib/bcel-5.2.jar";"lib/rsyntax.jar";"client.jar" -javaagent:"LSA.jar"=config.js -jar client.jar
```

I have a program which I want to run in Ubuntu. This is the run.bat script that I have been using in windows.

To get the client file working I understand

```
java -jar client.jar
```

But to get everything working I dont understand how to replace `"c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_75\bin\java.exe"`.

Comment: Run `which java` and replace it with that output

Comment: As with other sequences of paths (e.g. in the PATH environment variable existing in both DOS and *nix), you'll likely need to replace the semicolons by colons, like `"lib/bcel-5.2.jar":"lib/rsyntax.jar":...`. You also can omit the semicolons unless the paths contain spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the command `which java` or `command -v java` and you get an output like:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

this means it's installed use `java` in place of `c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_75\bin\java.exe`.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

At the top of that file.

Comment: Obviously there is no need to use a path when java is in the path ;-). And if it isn't, `which` will come up empty-handed as well.

Answer (score 4):

If java is in your PATH you can just say "java" (no need to find out where it is with `which`). If it isn't, you must find out where your (non-standard) install placed it, and simply use that path to the java program (`which` etc. wouldn't help you here).

Note that you'll probably also need to replace the semicolons in the class path with colons, as is the *nix fashion. I can imagine the Linux java doesn't handle semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

You must see what flavor of Java do you have in your box.
Type this to identify it:

```
update-alternatives --query java
```

In my computer, I have found these (e.g):

```
~$ update-alternatives --query java
Name: java
Link: /usr/bin/java
Slaves:
 java.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Value: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Alternative: /opt/dev/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java
Priority: 100
Slaves:

Alternative: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Priority: 1081
Slaves:
 java.1.gz /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

You can choose best (usually highest priority) javapath, so you can build your script based on it.

Comment: "Some applications don't support openjdk" which ones? OpenJDK is at least as capable as Oracle Java, OpenJFX is available for Ubuntu which allows to use JavaFX, Icedtea-web allows to use Java Webstart, you have absolutely no excuse to stick to Oracle Java. I haven't downvoted your answer because the disagreement concerns only a small part of it.

Comment: Ok, @gouessej,  I edited. I had problems using OpenJDK, but I'll put outside my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help I did need to replace the semicolons and use

java -jar at the  beginning.

Thanks everyone

Fred

Comment: Yes, the class path entries are separated by semicolons only under Windows, they are separated by colons under all other operating systems according to the "man" (enter "man java" in the terminal and look at the section about the class path).